# Setting up domain names locally for testing?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dns, xampp

I will be using one hosting account with several domains parked on it along with a main domain name. I need to be able to show different content based on what domain is being accessed. So, my question is, how can I test this locally?

- I have Vista
- I use XAMPP

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define multiple domains in your hosts file.

you can find it *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*

There are examples written there to help you understand, how it works. then create a page lets say index.php and parse the domain there and redirect it to relevant domain.

Comment: Do you mean machine name ? like myhostname.local ?